# How to insert custom view on the bottom of tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In the case of loss network, I'd like to insert a custom view on the bottom of table view but **not overlap** the table view. This custom view still appear even the user leave their finger on screen and only disappear after a period of time or network come backs. It likes the behaviour of Facebook app. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: did you look at tableFooterView?

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen For this kind of functionality you have to add logic for it . At the tableview initialise time you have to add one custom view in tableview last row .

Comment: there are multiple ways  1.  Add footerView in tableview.   2.   Add a view on last visible cell to show alert to user.  3.  Add a view on bottom below the tableview. Once network losses, decrease the size of tableview with the height of Customview.

Answer (score 3):

```
//Give size of view as u want 
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50))

//add this view in footer section of tableview
youTableview.tableFooterView = customView
```

Comment: if its helpful for you please accept this because other can find easyly..

Answer (score 0):

You can do set footer as per below screenshot.

[image]